# Is there a way to clean this POST request of backslashes before I send it off?

Tags: go, http, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm writing a program that sends a POST request whose body requires double quotes in plaintext. Because I'm injecting variables with `fmt.Sprintf` everytime I send a request, I'm using string literals when sending the request off

```
func searchLocalImage(imageName, imageTag, artifactoryUsername, artifactoryPassword string) (localImageRepo string) {
    a := types.ArtifactoryClient{
        Url:      "<url>",
        Username: artifactoryUsername,
        Password: artifactoryPassword,
        Client:   resty.New(),
    }
    var responseBody map[string]interface{}

    url := a.Url + "/search/aql"
    res, _ := a.Client.R().
        SetHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain").
        SetBasicAuth(a.Username, a.Password).
        SetBody(fmt.Sprintf(`items.find({"$and": [{"repo":{"$match":"<folder>"}},{"path": {"$match":"%s/%s"}},{"name":{"$match":"<tag>"}}]}).include("repo","path","name")`, imageName, imageTag)).
        Post(url)
```

Of course, this automatically injects escape characters to returned string.

```
"items.find({\"$and\": [{\"repo\":{\"$match\":\"<folder>\"}},{\"path\": {\"$match\":\"<folderPath>\"}},{\"name\":{\"$match\":\"<tag>\"}}]}).include(\"repo\",\"path\",\"name\")"
```

This unfortunately results in the response being an error message. Has anybody found a way to send a request like this the way I would need to without also sending those backslashes?

Comment: If the backslashes weren’t there, it wouldn’t be valid JSON, and your content-type claims it is JSON.

Comment: You might wanna use `text/plain` instead since the beginning part doesn't meet the JSON standard

Comment: Changed the content-type. Still receiving the same error, because there are backslashes in something that does not read backslashes. For additional information, I pasted the formatted request body into Insomnia (where I'd correctly tested the AQL call before), and with the backslashes, it returns an error.

Comment: editted original post to reflect what my code is now.

Comment: "this automatically injects escape characters to returned string" -- No, no it doesn't. It adds escape characters when you _display_ it, so that it can be represnted visually in a meaningful way. But the string in memory does not contain that.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I didn't know that until I saw the accepted answer below. The problem was actually beyond request, but I was short sighted in my debugging because of an assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course, this automatically injects escape characters to returned string.

No, this is not true. You see the escape characters because the tool that you used (most likely a debugger) displays the content as a quoted string.

You can simply dump the request to see what is sent. And paste the dump content into Insomnia to find out what's wrong.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/http/httputil"

    "github.com/go-resty/resty/v2"
)

func main() {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        buf, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%s\n", buf)
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    client := resty.New()

    imageName := "image name"
    imageTag := "image tag"
    _, err := client.R().
        SetHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain").
        SetBasicAuth("<username>", "<password>").
        SetBody(fmt.Sprintf(`items.find({"$and": [{"repo":{"$match":"<folder>"}},{"path": {"$match":"%s/%s"}},{"name":{"$match":"<tag>"}}]}).include("repo","path","name")`, imageName, imageTag)).
        Post(ts.URL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:41937
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Basic PHVzZXJuYW1lPjo8cGFzc3dvcmQ+
Content-Length: 156
Content-Type: text/plain
User-Agent: go-resty/2.7.0 (https://github.com/go-resty/resty)

items.find({"$and": [{"repo":{"$match":"<folder>"}},{"path": {"$match":"image name/image tag"}},{"name":{"$match":"<tag>"}}]}).include("repo","path","name")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was seeing the escape characters in the debugger.

It must be something else, because the request that's being generated is correct. But being able to dump the request has proven useful, I appreciate it Zeke.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted if you think that it answers the question. But a stackoverflow question is not like a github issue, there is not "close" action, lol.